# Como imprir cada digito de un numero

Tags: python

Necesito que imprima cada digito del numero ingresado, pero el unico que me muestra de manera correcta es el ultimo, los otros dos aparecen en decimales.

```
 num=int(input('Ingrese un numero '))
 if 100 <= num <= 999 or -999 <= num <= -100:
    if num < 0:
       print('El numero ingresado es negativo')
 d1=num/100
 d2=num%100/10
 d3=num%100%10
 print('El numero ingresado es de 3 digitos')
 print(d1)
 print(d2)
 print(d3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando expresiones regulares:

```
import re

num = input('Ingrese un numero ')
for d in re.findall("(\d)", num):
    print(d)
```

Funciona para números de cualquier tamaño y signo:

```
Ingrese un numero -38438834
3
8
4
3
8
8
3
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya supe cual era mi error y era que me faltaba indicar que queria que el resultado me lo mostrara de forma entera.

```
 num=int(input('Ingrese un numero '))
 if 100 <= num <= 999 or -999 <= num <= -100:
      if num < 0:
      print('El numero ingresado es negativo')
 d1=num//100  ---> era solo agregar otro '/' aqui
 d2=num%100//10 ----> y aqui
 d3=num%100%10
 print('El numero ingresado es de 3 digitos')
 print(d1)
 print(d2)
 print(d3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Has solucionado tu pregunta pero en todo caso es bueno saber esta alternativa:

---

Consiste en descomponer la "lista" en formato "str" de la variable *num* (donde dice *unpack*).

```py
num=input('Ingrese un numero ')

if len(num)==3:
    d1,d2,d3=num #unpack

print(d1,d2,d3,type(d1))
```

Output: `4 6 7 <class 'str'>`

*Observese que el tipo de dato es 'str'*

---

Para convertir cada uno en 'int' puedes iterar un ciclo for para cada elemento, con 'list comprehension' sería: `[int(n) for n in num]` y quedaría:

```py
num=input('Ingrese un numero ')

if len(num)==3:
    d1,d2,d3=[int(n) for n in num]

print(d1,d2,d3,type(d1))
```

Output: `4 6 7 <class 'int'>`

*Observese que el tipo de dato es 'int'*

Answer (score 0):

También válida pasándola a str() y viendo la longitud del string.
Luego la recorres también en str() para mostrar los números y en caso que sea negativo no mostramos'-' para que no lo cuente cómo dígito ni lo muestre

```
num=int(input('Ingrese un numero '))
digitos= len(str(num))
if num<0:
  print('El número {} es negativo y tiene {} dígitos'.format(num, digitos-1))
else:
  print('Tiene {} dígitos\n'.format(digitos))
for i in str(num):
  if i!='-':
    print(i)
```